# What in the world is ctfmon.exe?

Tags: windows, services

I seem to see "ctfmon.exe" in the running tasks of every Windows PC I've used.  I've always called it "capture the flag monitor."  What is it really used for, do I need it, and if not, can I safely remove it?

Comment: +1 for "Capture The Flag!"  Laughed loud enough that people wondered if I was off my rocker...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Frequently Asked Questions About ctfmon.exe

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282599

> **What Does the Ctfmon.exe File Do?**
>
> Ctfmon.exe monitors the active windows
>   and provides text input service
>   support for speech recognition,
>   handwriting recognition, keyboard,
>   translation, and other alternative
>   user input technologies.

Answer (score 1):

[Its a process that runs on opening of a Windows XP office program](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/ctfmon.exe.html)

Answer (score 1):

This site gives you processes information:

http://www.liutilities.com/products/wintaskspro/processlibrary/ctfmon/